# Gmail API in IOS asks for authorization every time the app is launched

Tags: ios, swift, gmail-api

I am using Gmail API to read mails from the user's Gmail account. Ideally the app should ask for username, password and authorization for the app to access user's gmail account once, but the app is asking for the above mentioned details every time.

I have followed the code mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift

Comment: If you dont want your users to be prompted for authorization everytime, then you should access_type="offline" instead of "online". check this link https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer for reference.

Comment: Where do I make the changes, I mean in which file @SGC

Comment: In your oauth code. please check the above link